# Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7.4 to 3.0.0 results in 404 on REST endpoints. Tomcat 10.1.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, http-status-code-404, endpoint

I recently attempted to upgrade my Spring Boot application from version 2.7.4 to 3.0.0. However, after making this upgrade, I encountered a problem where my REST endpoints are returning a 404 error, and I can't figure out why.

Here are the details of the issue:

I have a Spring Boot application with RESTful endpoints defined in a Controller class.
Prior to the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0, everything was working as expected.
After upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.0, when I try to access any of my REST endpoints, I receive a 404 error.
I've checked my code, and the mappings in my Controller class appear to be correct. Additionally, I've verified that the application is starting up without any errors or exceptions.

Here's a simplified example of my Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/App")


public class Controller { 

    private Service service;

    public void setService(Service service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/Add",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseDTO addUser(@RequestBody RequestDTO user){
        return service.addUser(user);
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/Find",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ResponseDTO> findUser(@RequestParam String name){
        return service.findUser(name);
    }
    @PutMapping(value = "/Update",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseDTO updateUser(@RequestBody ResponseDTO user,@RequestParam UUID id){
        return service.updateUser(user,id);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/Delete",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ResponseDTO> deleteUser(@RequestParam String name){
        return service.deleteUser(name);
    }

}
```

I also have a SpringConfigurationFactory class where I create beans for my Controller and Service classes:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfigurationFactory {

    @Bean(name = "Controller")
   
    public Controller controllerBean (){
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.setService(serviceBean());
        return controller;
    }

    @Bean(name = "Service")
    public Service serviceBean(){
        return new Service();
    }
}
```

What I Tried:

Upgraded my Spring Boot project from 2.7.4 to 3.0.0.
Verified that my SpringConfigurationFactory class is correctly creating beans.
Implemented @ComponentScan to ensure my components are scanned correctly.
Implemented WebMvcConfigurer to configure my application.
Checked the Spring Boot documentation for any changes in configuration for version 3.0.0.

I expected my project to work seamlessly after the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0, with all my REST endpoints functioning as they did in the previous version.

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.0, I encountered a 404 error when trying to access my REST endpoints. The endpoints were working correctly before the upgrade, so this issue seems related to the version change